# Scaling images in a picture box visual studio

Tags: c#, winforms, image-scaling

I'm working on a program where you can make 8-bit sprites and then use them to make a map.  The problem is when I put them in the picture boxes (used as tiles for the map editor) they become blurred due to the scaling.  Is there any way to get around this? (I'm using visual studio windows forms and c#)

Comment: Saving your tiles as jpg should improve scaling. It however makes more sense to ensure that your picture boxes have the same dimensions at the tiles, even if that means some move offscreen.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you actually want to achieve? Should be trivial to render non-scaled image, but I suspect you are after something else...

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you set the [`SizeMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode(v=vs.110).aspx) of your `PictureBox` properly for your scenario.

As you do not want to scale them, I suggest you put them to `Normal` or `Zoom`

`Normal` with align the picture on the TopLeft position of the PictureBox. `Zoom` will stretch, but maintain the ratio (thus it wont be overly blurry)